# JPA TypedQuery#getResultStream vs Hibernate Query#setResultListTransformer in terms of Performance?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have to query for about 20 to 30 results where some of the tables have m:n relations which I want to fetch their ids as well. So Hibernate ends up with the following SQL statement:

```sql
select
    p1_0.person_id,
    pp1_0.parent_person_id 
from
    person p1_0 
left join
    dependent_person pp1_0 
        on p1_0.person_id=pp1_0.child_person_id 
where
    p1_0.person_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

The result sets for example look as follows:

| person_id | parent_person_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

I want to project these rows to a `DTO` respectively to a `Map<Long, Set<Long>>` and don't want to stress any overheads to Hibernate's persistence context since there is no further need for the entities. So my question is now:

In concern of performance, which of the 2 following approaches is the better one:

1. Get a result stream from the JPA TypedQuery#getResultStream method and collect the data to a Map using the Java Stream Collector API
2. unwrwap to `org.hibernate.query.Query.class` and set a custom Hibernate's `ResultListTransformer` to return the desired Map

I know that the setup of a Java Stream is costly and for only a few items a more or less slow process since the build up and tear down take their time. But unwrapping and hooking in a ResultListTransformer feels to cry for overhead as well.

Is there any knowledge about which way to go in terms of performance?
Many thanks for any clarification

Comment: Stay clear of `jakarta.persistence.Query#getResultStream` - it is broken by design

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov thanks for this information. Can you be a little more specific or maybe have link at hand?

Comment: the only reason to use `Query#getResultStream` is the existence of some corner cases when you need to process the worth of data which does not fit into heap - that is definitely not your case. Moreover, pls read javadoc for `org.hibernate.query.Query#stream`: "**You should call Stream.close()** after processing the stream so that the underlying resources are deallocated right away" - as soon as you start using `Query#getResultStream` you turn your fancy code into `try-with-resources` mess.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Many thanks for this accurate information, that really helps - like always when I stumble across some answers of you ;)